# Join based on ID and combined number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a tables like below to simply my case I took `emp` and `dept`

EMP:

```
+----+-------+------+
| ID | Name  | Dept |
+----+-------+------+
| A1 | John  | 0010 |
| A2 | Jack  | 1010 |
| A3 | Jill  | 1100 |
| A4 | James | 0001 |
+----+-------+------+
```

DEPT

```
+---------+------------+
| DEPT_ID | DEPT_NAME  |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | HR         |
| 2       | Audit      |
| 3       | Competency |
| 4       | Manager    |
+---------+------------+
```

My expected Output

```
+----+-------+------------+------+
| ID | Name  | DeptName   | Dept |
+----+-------+------------+------+
| A1 | John  | Competency | 0010 |
| A2 | Jack  | HR         | 1010 |
| A2 | Jack  | Competency | 1010 |
| A3 | Jill  | HR         | 1100 |
| A3 | Jill  | Audit      | 1100 |
| A4 | James | Manager    | 0001 |
+----+-------+------------+------+
```

Logic.

I have to find the Deptname from `Department` table based on `Dept` column in emp table. It will be always 4 digits and each correspond to 1 department. If there is 1 in the first place, then it is HR, if 1 in second place then it Audit. If there are 1 in multiple places, then they corresponds to all the departments. I really dont know why it was designed like this. I'm trying to figure this out.

I have tried something like below, but it is not giving all the rows.

```
select * from emp join dept on 1 = substring(dept,dept_id+1,1)
```

[FIDDLE HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3730d2cb935b44442dea39e8baa043df)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a HORRIBLE data model and you should fix it.   If employees can be assigned to multiple departments, this is the wrong way to handle it.  You should have a table with one row per employee and per assigned department.

That said, if you are stuck with this model, you can use some big fiddling:

```
select *
from emp e join
     dept d
     on convert(int, e.dept) & convert(int, power(2, d.dept_id)) <> 0
order by e.id, d.dept_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1896c948e239dd55d2b9d13c3a0cfb33) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  This works for your example with four departments.  However, if you have more departments than bits in an integer, then this will start to reach its limits (you can switch to a `bigint`).  If that is an issue, I would suggest that you ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. Yes i agree that it is horrible model. The actual scenario is  assigning roles to user. I have 12 such roles. I will try to use `BIGINT`. Thanks again.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is that  `&` in the join condition. is it same as `and` ? I never knew we can use  `&` like this. Can u pls provide some reference to learn that?

Comment: @Avinash . . . For 12 roles, you can use an integer, but if you have control over the data model almost *anything* else would be better -- even listing the roles as a comma delimited string (which I also abhor).  The `&` is a bitwise operator:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15.